# How to access Redux props within React Navigation functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm adding Redux to my React Native project and facing the following issue.

There is a screen **Screen1**:

```
const Screen1 = ({ navigation }) => {
    // ... do some stuff
    const goToScreen2 = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Screen2');
    }

    // how to access prop1 here???
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        prop1: state.myDesireProp
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Screen1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add prop1 in screen1 params like this:

```
const Screen1 = ({ navigation, prop1}) => {
// ... do some stuff
const goToScreen2 = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Screen2');
}}
```